# React Konva Rotation/Revolution Animation

Tags: reactjs, konvajs, react-konva, konva, konvajs-reactjs

Hey I am new to react konva. I am creating a project in which i want a rectangle to revolves around an object. Can anybody advise me on how to achieve this. Any help is much appreciated

```
    <div>
      <Stage width={500} height={500}>
        <Layer>
            <Rect ///<=this rect is the center object
              width={50}
              height={100}
              x={20}
              y={20}
              strokeWidth={2}
              stroke="red"
              fill="blue"
              opacity={1}         
            />
        
            <Rect ///<=this rect should revolve around it
              width={50}
              height={100}
              x={50}
              y={50}
              strokeWidth={2}
              stroke="black"
              fill="black"
              opacity={1}         
            />
        </Layer>
      </Stage>
      <Button onClick={handleRotate}>Start Rotation</Button>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the `.rotate` property of node

```
const ref=useRef(null)

useEffect(() => {
  
    var rect= ref.current;
    var anim = new Konva.Animation((frame) => {
      rect?.rotate((frame.timeDiff *90) / 1000);
    }, rect?.getLayer());
    anim?.start();
    
  }, [input]);

<Rect
ref={ref}
/>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Konva.Animation` to move the rectangle as you want it. It is up to you to calculate position of the shape.

```js
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { Stage, Layer, Rect } from "react-konva";
import Konva from "konva";

const App = () => {
  const rectRef = React.useRef();
  const [animating, setAnimation] = React.useState(false);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (!animating) {
      return;
    }
    const node = rectRef.current;
    const anim = new Konva.Animation(
      (frame) => {
        const centerX = 200;
        const centerY = 200;
        const radius = 200;

        node.x(centerX + radius * Math.cos(frame.time / 1000));
        node.y(centerY + radius * Math.sin(frame.time / 1000));
      },
      [node.getLayer()]
    );
    anim.start();
    return () => anim.stop();
  }, [animating]);
  return (
    <>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setAnimation(!animating);
        }}
      >
        Toggle animation
      </button>
      <Stage width={window.innerWidth} height={window.innerHeight}>
        <Layer>
          <Rect
            x={200}
            y={200}
            width={100}
            height={100}
            fill="red"
            shadowBlur={10}
          />
          <Rect
            ref={rectRef}
            width={100}
            height={100}
            fill="blue"
            shadowBlur={10}
            // set default position
            // animation will overwrite it
            x={400}
            y={200}
          />
        </Layer>
      </Stage>
    </>
  );
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-konva-animate-rotation-bxbtj

Comment: I think this one is more correct because the current accepted answer from theta28 was not really answering the question. Even if it was implemented correctly, the second box will also rotate. In contrast, this solution make sure the blue box stays in it's rotation, only translating around the red box.